# Where to place the email template in IBM BPM 8.5?

Tags: websphere-8

I am trying to send email from BPM process Designer,although email is sent but i want to read the Email body content from XML file and i am facing the problem i.e where to place this XML template file on server so that the path is found able to my service at run time.

It will be highly appreciated if anyone can help me how to do this?

Regards,
Awais